# Get day from string in spanish PHP

Tags: php, date, localization

I'm trying with:

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
 $string = "24/11/2014";
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $string);
 echo $date->format("l");
```

And I'm getting Monday, which is correct but I need it in spanish, so, is there any way to retrieve this day in spanish?

Comment: I think the function you need is [strftime](https://php.net/strftime)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the DateTime format page:

> This method does not use locales. All output is in English.

If you need locales look into [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)
Example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
$string = "24/11/2014";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $string);
echo strftime("%A",$date->getTimestamp());
```

Comment: perfect, clean and elegant

Comment: Nice answer. After learning this I realized I needed to do 'locale -a' in my shell to find out the correct name for the locale (e.g. 'es_ES.utf8'). Thought it would be useful to leave this here.

Comment: Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Alternatives to this function include:

date()
IntlDateFormatter::format()

Answer (score 8):

I use:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
echo iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($row['date'])));
```

or

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES@euro","es_ES","esp");
```

both works. I have to use `iconv` to avoid strange symbols in accents, and i obtain this result:

```
domingo, 09 de octubre de 2016
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `strftime` function:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL,"es_ES@euro","es_ES","esp" );
echo strftime( "%A %d de %B del %Y" );
```

or

```
function SpanishDate($FechaStamp)
{
   $ano = date('Y',$FechaStamp);
   $mes = date('n',$FechaStamp);
   $dia = date('d',$FechaStamp);
   $diasemana = date('w',$FechaStamp);
   $diassemanaN= array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles",
                  "Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
   $mesesN=array(1=>"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio",
             "Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
   return $diassemanaN[$diasemana].", $dia de ". $mesesN[$mes] ." de $ano";
}
```

Comment: Sadly strftime is now deprecated, and the intldateformatter functions need the intl extension be installed on php. So the easiest way is to use a handmade function.

Answer (score 5):

[strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) has been **DEPRECATED** as of PHP 8.1.0

Another alternative is using [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.formatobject.php):

```
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
    'es_ES',
    \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    'Europe/Madrid' //more in: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php
);

echo $formatter->formatObject(new \DateTime(), "eeee", "es_ES");
```

- note that "eeee" is a format from [ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax)

Comment: For those of you trying this, you need to install intl extension for php and enable it in your php.ini file

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it.

```
// Define key-value array
$days_dias = array(
'Monday'=>'Lunes',
'Tuesday'=>'Martes',
'Wednesday'=>'Miércoles',
'Thursday'=>'Jueves',
'Friday'=>'Viernes',
'Saturday'=>'Sábado',
'Sunday'=>'Domingo'
);

//lookup dia based on day name
$dia =  $days_dias[date('l', strtotime("1993-04-28"))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging a bit on how to do this, most of the times people use the function [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

Unfortunately, the `strftime` function has been **DEPRECATED** as of PHP 8.1.0 and 'is highly discouraged' to rely on it.

You have two options:

1. Use the [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.formatobject.php) function, but you need to install the [intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension for `php` and enable it in your `php.ini` file. This can be problematic in some shared production environments. The good side is you keep the output masks and if you use other languages you can easily exchange between them.

   The code would be like this:

   ```
   $d = new IntlDateFormatter('es_ES', null, null, null, null, null, 'dd MMMM y');
   print($d->format(new DateTime('2022-12-01'));
   ```

   and the output would be like this `01 Diciembre 2022`
2. Use a handmade function so you can reuse it several times. It is easier and faster to use, but you lose output masks and is tied to a single language.

   The code would be like this:

   ```
   function fechaEspanol($fecha)
   {
    $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'; //This is an optional input format mask for datetime database extracted info
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $fecha); //A simple $d = new DateTime($fecha) can also be used
    $anio = $d->format('Y');
    $mes = $d->format('n');
    $dia = $d->format('d');
    $diasemana = $d->format('w');

    $diassemanaN = array("Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado");
    $mesesN = array(1 => "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
    return "{$diassemanaN[$diasemana]}, $dia de {$mesesN[$mes]} de $anio";
   }
   ```

   If `fechaEspanol('2022-12-01 12:00:00')` the output would be like this `01 Diciembre 2022`. This function can be optimized, but is put like this for a clearer view of what is being done.

I hope this helps someone.