# Is there a fast way to convert date to spanish?

Tags: php

With this:

```
date( 'd F Y', strtotime( $row["datestart"] ) )
```

I get this:

```
08 July 2016
```

But I need to get this:

```
08 Julio 2016
```

Julio is July in spanish.

I have added this to the top of the php page:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
```

but it doesn't work.

So what can I do ?

Comment: ` setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");` But it often does not work. Write your own function

Comment: @splash58 Why often doesn't it work ?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635303/get-day-from-string-in-spanish-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635303/get-day-from-string-in-spanish-php)
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718115/trying-to-display-a-date-in-spanish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718115/trying-to-display-a-date-in-spanish)

Comment: @xRobot Whenever i tried it, date was in english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish'); 
$date = str_replace("/","-","08/07/2016");
echo strftime('%d %B %Y',strtotime($date)); // 08 julio 2016
```

`setlocale` is the key ingredient here.

*update*: **PHP 8.x**

```
$format = new IntlDateFormatter('es_ES', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, NULL, NULL, 'dd MMMM y');
echo $format->format(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
```

Use `format` to output the `DateTime` to the locale you specify in `IntlDateFormatter` (`DateTimeZone` is optional).

Comment: Sadly, now strftime is now deprecated in PHP 8.1

Comment: @ElGucs: Answer edited to include example for `PHP 8.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant you may use:

Install `intl` extension for `php` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)).
Enable it in your `php.ini` file and then you will be able to check it is working with the following sample:

```
$f = new IntlDateFormatter('es_ES', null, null, null, null, null, 'dd MMMM y');
print($f->format(new DateTime('2016-07-08'));
```

An expected output will be the following:
`08 julio 2016`

Answer (score 1):

You could make an associative array.
Set the keys to the months in English and the values to the corresponding months in Spanish.

It would look something like this...

```
$months = array(
  'january' => 'enero',
  'february' => 'febrero',
  'march' => 'marzo',
  'april' => 'abril',
  'may' => 'mayo',
  'june' => 'junio',
  'july' -> 'julio',
  'august' => 'agosto',
  'september' => 'septiembre',
  'october' => 'octubre',
  'november' => 'noviembre',
  'december' => 'diciembre'
);
```

Then you could reference the months like this...

```
$enMonth = "july"; //This is the month in English that you will match to the corresponding month in Spanish.

$esMonth = $months[$enMonth]; //You are returning the value (which is Spanish) of the key (which is English), giving you the month in Spanish.
```

You could probably also use Google Translate's API, but it seems like too much for something that can be done with a simple array.

Here is [Google Translate's API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/translate-reference) if you are interested in translating other words, or a larger array of words.